# How to focus bootstrap select picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I've use data-live-search for searchable option. When I click on focus button it should focus again select. I've use following code

```js
$("#focus").click(function() {
  $(".selectpicker").focus();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="4444">4444</option>
  <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
  <option value="Elite">Elite</option>
  <option value="Interp">Interp</option>
  <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
<button id="focus">focus</button>
```

Whenever I press enter t is focus to select box but search option is not shown. I've attach [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpsaU.png)
Please give me suggestion for display proper option with search option when I enter it

Answer (score 2):

`focus()` not working because it turned to customized `select` not native select option, by the way there is a native way to do this in `selectpicker` plugin, an event called `toggle`

```js
$("#focus").click(function() {
  // toggle
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle');

  // select by value
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'Test');
  $('.remove-example').selectpicker('refresh');

  // change highlight
  $('.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="selectpicker">
  <option value="4444">4444</option>
  <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
  <option value="Elite">Elite</option>
  <option value="Interp">Interp</option>
  <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
<button id="focus">focus</button>
```

Comment: but by default it is highlight by default selected value suppose i want to highlight 4444. How it could highlight this. I've use 
         $('.selectpicker').val("4444");
        $('.selectpicker').trigger("change"); still it is highlight by default value

Comment: @VaishnaviDeshpande Forget `jQ` or `JS` method to do this, like `trigger` `change` or etc. it's a plugin, it has own method do something, like what I used `toggle`, let me check  I'll update my answer, but be aware, this is new question *!*

Comment: Thanks for you time and sorry for apathy when I try your code it's work but instead of written all question for minor query I've comment on question